# How to rectify type computation with a concrete type? eg number is not assignable to value ComputedType<T>

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
type IsNumeric = 'int';
type IsString = 'str';
type IsId = IsNumeric | IsString;
type CalcValue<IdType extends IsId> = IdType extends IsNumeric
  ? number
  : IdType extends IsString
  ? string
  : never;
type IdStruct<IdType extends IsId> = {
  readonly idName: IdType;
  readonly value: CalcValue<IdType>;
};

class IdStructFactory<IdType extends IsId> {
  constructor(readonly idName: IdType) {}
  create(value: CalcValue<IdType>): IdStruct<IdType> {
    return { idName: this.idName, value: value };
  }
}

function makeIdFromNumber<T extends IsNumeric>(
  idStructFactory: IdStructFactory<T>,
  x: number,
): IdStruct<T> {
  return idStructFactory.create(x);
}
```

I get the error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CalcValue<T>'`

I think that I understand what is happening...the compiler doesn't know how to unify number and the CalcValue value

I guess I'm wondering if there is a way to do something like the above with CalcValue, but be able to reference a concrete type.

note that I realize that makeIdFromNumber could be written as so

```
function makeIdFromNumber<T extends IsNumeric>(
  idStructFactory: IdStructFactory<T>,
  x: CalcValue<T>,
): IdStruct<T> {
  return idStructFactory.create(x);
}
```

but this has to do with the contrived nature of the example. this issue came up in code which relies on various functions which return concrete types, eg numbers.

I guess a function like `canThisExist(v: number): CalcValue<T>` is what I want...well, other than just casting it, which I do not want!

Edit:
the goal of this question is to see if there is a way to define a function roughly with the signature `function makeIdFromNumber<???>(idStructFactory: IdStructFactory<???>, x: number,): IdStruct<T>`. I am wondering if there are any ways to sort of restructure what I am doing above, perhaps get the same result but via a different approach, etc that allows unifying number and CalcValue, or something to that effect.

Comment: Why is the function generic if `T` can only ever be `IsNumeric`?

Comment: Tobias, this is a stripped down example. You'll note there is a "IsString" type defined above...so the goal would be to also have functions the, when T is a subtype of IsString, rely on being able to create an id using a string, and so on

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this question. Are you looking for a "why"-answer which explains why `number` is not assignable  to `CalcValue<T>` or are you looking for a workaround? It seems like there is already a workaround in the question, but you imply that it would not work for the non-stripped down code. This would also make it hard for us to make suggestions, when we can't know for sure if it also works for your real code.

Comment: fair question, and I just updated the question. but the tldr is I'm wondering if the same thing can be accomplished in another way, or if there is some type level technique that will allow me to unify number with CalcValue. in other languages I've used with richer type systems there are, but I do not know typescript's compiler well enough to know how to accomplish more complicated things like this.